# как распарсить mhtml файл?

Tags: php, парсер

Задача данные из файла положить в базу. Для этого мне нужно распарсить файл, но я столкнулся с проблемой. 
Данные в файле закодированы, и явно не отображаются. В исходном виде строка выглядит вот так:

```
<TR>
        <TD align=3D"right">1</TD>
        <TD>=D0=92=D0=BE=D0=BB=D0=B3=D0=B0</TD>
        =
    <TD>=D0=99=D0=BE=D1=88=D0=BA=D0=B0=D1=80-=D0=9E=D0=BB=D0=B8=D0=BD=D1=81=D0==BA=D0=B8=D0=B9</TD>
        <TD>mobile</TD>
        <TD>=D1=8F=D0=BD=D0=B2=D0=B0=D1=80=D1=8C - =D0=BC=D0=B0=D0=B9</TD>
        <TD align=3D"right">2020</TD>
        <TD align=3D"right">22</TD>
        <TD align=3D"right">109</TD>
        <TD align=3D"right">88% (8/9)</TD>
</TR>
```

то есть некоторые значения в ячейках не явные. 
Подскажите можно ли распарсить такой формат?

Comment: закодирован в MIME multipart/related.

Comment: quoted_printable_decode()

Comment: @splash58 в целом вариант рабочий спасибо) Есть одно но, как всегда: строка - =D0=99=D0=BE=D1=88=D0=BA=D0=B0=D1=80-=D0=9E=D0=BB=D0=B8=D0=BD=D1=81=D0==BA=D0=B8=D0=B9  , отображается Йошкар-Олинс�=�ий по причине того что на моменте где дублируется равно, нет символа переноса строки. Увидел в других строках перенос есть. Вопрос в том, мне думать алгоритм который если встечает двойное равно, без переноса строки вставлял символ переноса, или  что-то попроще есть?)

Comment: не уверен, что есть автоматический вариант

Comment: @splash58 спасибо за подсказку!

Answer (score 0):

quoted_printable_decode() - функция php которая меня устроила.
Подсказал @splash58, спасибо!